# Gensim worker thread stuck

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, gensim, doc2vec

I am training document embeddings on a ~20 million sentences and using parallel processing in gensim. I'm creating my model and training with the following code

```
class read_corpus(object):

    def __init__(self, fname, n):
        self.fname = fname
        self.n = n

    def __iter__(self):
        num_notes = 0
        with open(self.fname, 'r') as f:
            while num_notes < n:
                note = next(f)
                sentence_id, sentence = note.split('\t')

                # remove the newline character after each line and split into words
                sentence = sentence[:-1].split(' ')

                # some processing


                yield TaggedDocument(sentence, [sentence_id])
                num_notes += 1


def model(fname, vector_size, min_count,
          n_epochs, model_name,
          n, prev_model_name=None):


    data = read_corpus(fname, n)

    if prev_model_name is not None:
        model = Doc2Vec.load(prev_model_name)
    else:
        model = Doc2Vec(vector_size=vector_size,
                        min_count=min_count,
                        workers=4,
                        window=8,
                        alpha=0.1,
                        min_alpha=0.0001)

        model.build_vocab(data)

    model.train(data, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=n_epochs)
    model.save(model_name)
```

After 6 - 8 epochs, the logging information shows that the training gets stuck waiting for a worker thread.
Note: the logging information says "EPOCH 1" because I'm training in a for loop.

`... 
INFO : EPOCH 1 - PROGRESS: at 99.71% examples, 162493 words/s, in_qsize 8, out_qsize 0
INFO : EPOCH 1 - PROGRESS: at 99.81% examples, 162528 words/s, in_qsize 7, out_qsize 0
INFO : EPOCH 1 - PROGRESS: at 99.91% examples, 162560 words/s, in_qsize 7, out_qsize 0
INFO : worker thread finished; awaiting finish of 3 more threads
INFO : worker thread finished; awaiting finish of 2 more threads`

It's been stuck here for several hours.

I had a similar output on a previous run. But the logging stopped at `INFO : worker thread finished; awaiting finish of 3 more threads`

Comment: I'm not sure what could cause this. What is the form of your `data` object, and are you sure it will always create an iterator that finishes completely without blocking? Why do you re-read it every iteration? Why do you re-save the model every iteration?

Comment: Separately, it's usually a bad idea to call `train()` multiple times, instead of just specifying your desired number of `epochs` and letting it do the looping. As you're doing it now, the learning-rate `alpha` is starting high for each epoch, then decaying to its minimum value by the end of the epoch, then starting high again at the beginning of the next iteration – a sawtooth pattern, and further always high for early data and low for late data. That won't cause a hang but isn't sensible or likely to give best results.

Comment: @gojomo thank you for the suggestions. `data` was a once only generator so I had to restart it each time it was exhausted. I don't think the iterator is the problem because the model sometimes finishes several epochs before getting stuck like this.  Regardless, I have fixed that and made it into a class like some tutorials. I was saving the model at each iteration because it kept getting stuck in the middle of training & so I wanted to ensure all progress was saved. I have fixed the issue of different training alpha at each epoch by manually specifying `model.alpha` and `model.min_alpha`

Comment: So is your problem now gone after the unshown changes to your code's `read_corpus()` and calls to `train()`, or still a problem? (It'd still be a good idea to fix/show what's being returned by `read_corpus()`. And it's still best to call `train()` once, letting it handle the alpha management, because that's so easy to get wrong that since it's not done right in the current code sample, and your altered code isn't shown, it could very well still be wrong.)

Comment: Unfortunately, those edits didn't solve the issue of the threads getting stuck. I have edited the post to include my updated model building code. I will attempt to run it without saving every iteration as per your suggestion (i.e. without the for loop) and post updates.

Comment: The problem could be in the unshown `read_corpus()` method – that's the most likely place for a problem that causes a blocked iterator. Collecting info on whether the cores are doing anything during the 'hang', and where any open-file pointers are, might shed more info on the hung-state. Your `alpha` isn't sawtoothing – good! – but note that `0.01` is an atypically-small starting alpha - values of 0.025 to 0.5 are most common in published work. (So I'd only go that small if your own meta-parameter optimization indicates that it works well for your data & other parameters.)

Comment: I have updated the the description with the code for `read_corpus`. I don't quite understand how that could be causing the problem since the program can run through several epochs (anywhere from 2 - 7) before hanging. I'll collect the CPU information and post an update. Thanks!

Comment: Could it be something in the elided `# some processing` area? Note: it's best to do any such per-line processing once, re-writing a simpler file (that may only need to be token-split), then driving the multiple iterations from that file. (Then, that extra processing is only done once, and outside of the potentially-bottlenecking master-IO-thread of the `Doc2Vec` training.) *If* the problem is in that processing, that might either trigger it early, or not at all. Also, is `fname` always a local-volume path (as opposed to some network volume that might have other issues)?

Comment: Not likely, I was just manipulating the sentence variable. Thank you for the feedback, I have switched to fewer workers and that seems to have resolved the hanging problem for the most part.

Comment: Hmm, if that helped, I might also especially watch logs/console/monitoring for memory-exhaustion – perhaps an unhandled `MemoryError` killed one of the threads, leaving the master thread waiting for results that would never come. (Peak memory use isn't strongly influenced by he `workers` count, compared to the giant shared vocabulary/weights structures, but maybe you're operating close to a limit.)

Comment: Happened to me too on two separate machines. "Solved" by switching to `workers=1`.